# Using AppCompat 'layout_behavior' with '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior' throws exception

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have a strange probem using the AppCompat Lib 22.2 with the new introduced: layout_behavior

If i use it with the value  "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" , as described here [Android Design Support Lib](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) the application terminates with the following exception:

```
Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.Settings
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.Settings
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.Settings
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/design/widget/Settings
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.Settings
```

If i change to :

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

everything works fine.

What i'm missing ?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: Hi, no i'm not using proguard.

See my build.gradle: http://hastebin.com/funijokudi.vbs

Comment: Shame on me. I must have accidentally exportet the string to my string.xml.

Comment: I had the same issue and it was indeed proguard.

Answer (score 56):

For others who encounter this exception and use proguard - you need to add following proguard rules:

```
-keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
```

or if you don't want to keep all of the design library components you can use:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class * extends android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior { *; }
```

Comment: The last line is unnecessary since it will be kept by line 2.

Comment: An important point is to force a Rebuild of your app. On my system the updated ProGuard settings were not being used.

Answer (score 37):

Another reason for this to be happening is when you're extending *FloatingActionButton.Behavior* and you don't have a (Context, AttributeSet) constructor. That happened to me with design library v. 23.0.1

Just add this constructor to your subclass:

```
public FloatingActionButtonBehaviorSubclass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
}
```

Comment: Great answer, also worth noting that this constructor applies to any subclass of CoordinatorLayout.Behavior; I had the same issue with BottomSheetBehavior.

Comment: i think the corresponding super call to your consctructor would be super(context, attrs); and not this one.

Comment: The support library version of `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` (at least in 23.2.0 which I'm currently using) doesn't override any constructor, so the parameterless one is the only available.

Answer (score 23):

You should add design lib for your project.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Check the sample https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 3):

For developers who are using getting this error only when using proguard, just add a single line to proguard rules file :

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior { *; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error today after migrating my project to Androidx.

It seems that I had a string in my string.xml file. I had to remove this line.

```
<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```

**It should only link to values.xml file and not string.xml file.**

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" should only link to values.xml (Ctrl+B)

```
<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```