# Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-design-library, android-proguard

help me, I have a problem with my app, when to run show me this error...help me, I have a problem with my app, when to run show me the next error...

Try setting the ProGuard but still do not know whether or proguard-rules.pro PROGuard - android.txt , am new to this please help me.

```
**09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.aes.avesdata.lapaz, PID: 32242
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aes.avesdata.lapaz/aes.avesdata.lapaz.activities.DetalleFTActivity}: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior**
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.t.<init>(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.a(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.q.setContentView(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at aes.avesdata.lapaz.activities.DetalleFTActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.t.<init>(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.a(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.q.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at aes.avesdata.lapaz.activities.DetalleFTActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.aes.avesdata.lapaz-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.t.<init>(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.a(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.q.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at aes.avesdata.lapaz.activities.DetalleFTActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815) 
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:          ... 27 more
09-22 16:37:22.236 32242-32242/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available**
```

Comment: [Here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30846201/383414) - and the trick is to force a full Rebuild of your app once you have made the changes.

Comment: `-keep class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior {*;}`

Answer (score 4):

Inside your project folder there is file named `proguard-rules.pro` all you have to do is include this line in that file

```
#For design support library
-keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
```

Now in your app's gradle file enable proguard for debug builds like this

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'jackson-rules.pro'
        }
```

`minifyEnabled true` enables the proguard for debug build.After testing your proguard configs ensure to set the flag to false!

Comment: minifyEnabled true on debug is not a good idea unless you know what you are doing, as it will increase the build time. Plus, it won't fix OPs problem.

Comment: it is definitely not a good idea.but i solved this issue by adding the above pro-guard rules.